# directory access is forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

the project is in php codeigniter3

after uploading the assets folder in the live server the webapp is giving error "directory access forbiden"

here are 3 .htaccess files i have for the project.
this one is for the main folder structure

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|fonts|images|css|less|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

/////////////////////////-----2-----///////////////////////////

this one is inside the applications folder

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

/////////////////////////-----3-----///////////////////////////
this one is inside the system folder

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Most likely the setting of the `Options` directive is different on that environment and does not grant directory access. You will have to change that: `Options +Indexes`

Comment: have you add `AllowOverride All` in apache conf? you can check this
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-set-up-htaccess-on-apache/

also make sure you give the right directory access in your project directory.

you can try to give access 777 for a while to make sure that's the problem